# Regex capture after second /

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to regex capture in Perl, all characters after the second occurrence of the `/` character.

using the the example:

```
/en-us/hello/world/newyork.html
```

I'd like to be able to capture:

```
hello/world/newyork.html
```

I tried:

```
^(?:[^\/]*\/){2}([^\/]*)
```

Only captures `hello` as group 1.

Comment: Use `/^(?:[^\/]*\/){2}(.*)/`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/l6sH8C/1).

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
\/[^\/]+\/(.*)
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z4gj5e/2)

Explanation:

- `\/[^\/]+\/` you first match everything till the second `/`:

  - `\/` the first slash
  - `[^\/]+`  one or more of chars that are not a slash
  - /` the second slash
- `(.*)` the substring you need is in the capturing group

Answer (score 0):

Is this URI parsing? It *looks* like URI parsing.

```
use URI qw();
my $u = URI->new;
$u->path('/en-us/hello/world/newyork.html');
my @s = $u->path_segments;
print join '/', @s[2..@s-1];
```